# How do I stop my code from writing the entire map at once to the terminal?

Tags: java, terminal

So, I'm making a 2d array map in Java and it's writing the whole map. This is obviously very laggy

```
public static final int WIDTH = 1000;
public static final int HEIGHT = 1000;

public static String[][] map = new String[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
```

How do I stop it from writing it all to the terminal, but instead print it out in sections to optimize it?
Here is the rest of my code:

```
static int x = 0, y = 5;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    myScreen = new MyScreen(TerminalFacade.createTerminal());
    myScreen.startScreen();
    myScreen.drawText("Dungeon Tredge", 0, 0, Color.RED);
    myScreen.drawText("(C) 3 on a Java course", 0, 1, Color.YELLOW);
    myScreen.drawText("TO DO: displayMap, addTree, addRock, addRoom", 0, 2,
            Color.YELLOW);
    myScreen.displayMap(0, y);
    myScreen.refresh();

    while (true) {
        Key key = myScreen.readInput();
        if (key != null)
            handleInput(key.getCharacter());

        if (myScreen.resizePending()) {
            myScreen.displayMap(0, y);
            myScreen.refresh();
        }
```

Comment: Do it on a different thead. Terminal output is asynchronously streamed anyway. Threads are as much part of Java as they are your shirt.

Comment: I don't see anything that actually displays to the terminal in this code. Maybe you need to provide the method implementations for `MyScreen`.

Comment: What exactly is this TerminalFacade that is being used in the code? There is a lot you are not telling here.